# Android 6.0 Location permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to implement runtime permission for location. The implementation is as follows:

```
public class MyLocationManager implements android.location.LocationListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static LocationManager m_locationManager;
    private static final int REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 999;
    private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 998;

    private String provider; 
    private Context mContext;

    public void startListenLocation(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;
        m_locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        ...

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION) ;
        } else {
            Location location = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //compiler error on the following line
                    Location myLocation = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                } else {
                    //Permission denied
                }
                return;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a syntax error when I call `getLastKnownLocation()` in `onRequestPermissionResult()`. It tells me to check permission again even though I had already done this. So can anyone tell what is wrong with my implementation here

Answer (score 3):

The method `getLastKnownLocation` is annotated with:

```
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
```

for this reason you get the warning:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

You have two options to avoid the warning:

1. Add a comment before the call `getLastKnownLocation`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {
           case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: 
           {
               if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                   //noinspection ResourceType
                   Location myLocation = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
               } else {
                   //Permission denied
               }
               return;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Refactor your code, add a method `getLastKnownLocationIfAllowed`:

   ```
   public void startListenLocation(Context context) {

       this.mContext = context;
       m_locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       if (!getLastKnownLocationIfAllowed())
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
   }

   private boolean getLastKnownLocationIfAllowed() {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           Location location = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
           return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```

   In your Activity:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {
           case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
               if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocationIfAllowed();
               } else {
                   //Permission denied
               }
               return;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

add this method on your activity and used that....

```
    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {return true;
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        flag=true;
        return true;
    }
}
```